# How to sign a transaction in metamask (EIP 712) with data instead of sending it normally to save gas cost?

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask

I have a function to set some additional metadata on a NFT card, it's not really expensive (seems that I only have to pay a couple bucks like sending a normal ETH tx) but I'd like to sign the transaction with metamask (EIP 712) instead of having to send it in order to save gas cost.

Let me describe it better with my code:

Smart contract function:

```
 function setNFTCardURI(uint256 tokenId, string memory cardURI) public {
        settokenId = tokenId;
        setcardURI = cardURI;
        
    }
```

My metamask tx to set the URI (everything works perfectly fine):

```
const txcard = {
                        'from': accounts[0],
                        'to': address,
                        'gas':gas,
                        'value':0,
                        'data': await NFTcontract.methods.setNFTCardURI(tokenidNFT,NFTCardurl).encodeABI()
                    };

                    const txcardhash = await ethereum.request({
                        method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
                        params: [txcard],
                    });
```

So how can I transform this transaction into a "sign transaction" when you only have to sign the message on the metamask popup (meaning no gas payed) with this message? :

```
("Sign this message to set your NFT Card metadata with the following values: 
- tokenId: tokenidNFT
- CardURI: NFTCardurl
)
```

Is that even possible?

I've looked around and found about Sign Typed Data (with versions updated from 1 to 4) and I know some DEX can sign transactions and orders, so my guess is that's possible, but it's out of my scope for the moment, hence this question here ;)

Comment: you can look how Augur does it and copy some code from sources

Comment: @stuart What are you trying to achieve with the signature? By itself [EIP-712](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712) is unrelated to saving gas it is just a cryptographic signature.

Comment: I'm trying to set these values into the smart contract related to their related NFT's (hence the variable names)